# Is there an easy way to partially backup Postgres?

Tags: backup, postgresql

I have a database running on postgres (8.4) and I want regular backups of parts of that data. We have very important data of which we need regular backups in case the hardware catches fire. But the same database contains a huge amount of binary data for each entry that grows really fast (easily more than a GB per day). Now, this data is not as critical. If we lose it, it is of course annoying, but it would be acceptable.

Is there an easy way to backup **some** of our tables with postgres, or do I have to manually write queries to copy everything somewhere before I can pgdump it?

Bonus: If the big binary table could just backup the last X entries, that would be perfect, but I am pretty sure I will have to do something as complex as this manually anway.

Comment: Are you aware of the "--table" option for pg_dump? Also, blobs don't get dumped when you use "--table" (unless you specify "--blobs").

Comment: Thank you, that solves my problem, I didn't realize there is such a parameter. If you had written this as an answer, I would accept it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the --table option for pg_dump, as suggested by Mark Wagner.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [**COPY**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-copy.html) command, but note that this sucks for incremental backups.

Another (possibly better depending) option may be a hot standby server that you shut down and take (filesystem-level) backups of periodically - This lets you use smarter tools which may take a binary diff of the DB table files and not have to suck down the whole thing every time you make a backup.
The other advantage is you have a well-knwon and well-supported recovery path this way :-)